# Pandas: add number of unique values to other dataset (as shown in picture):

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add the number of unique values in column C (right table) to the related row in the left table based on the values in common column A (as shown in the picture):

[image]

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Groupby`** column **A** in second dataset and calculate `count` of each unique value in column **C**. `merge` it with first dataset on column **A**. Rename column **C** to **C-count** if needed:

```
>>> count_df = df2.groupby('A', as_index=False).C.nunique()
>>> output = pd.merge(df1, count_df, on='A')
>>> output.rename(columns={'C':'C-count'}, inplace=True)
>>> output
   A   B  C-count
0  2  22        3
1  3  23        2
2  5  21        1
3  1  24        1
4  6  21        1
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I changed the picture to make the question more clear. Values is column C are not unique. I just added ".C.count()" to the end of first line.

Comment: Sorry, first line should change to: count_df = df2.groupby('A', as_index=False).C.nunique()

Comment: @A.Froughian - yop, then it will be correct.

Comment: @Ank was correct answering the previous edition of the question. I changed the question a bit. thank you all friends.

Comment: Saw your updated question just now. I see you already accepted @jezrael 's answer, but have updated my answer just for the future reference.

Comment: @Ank. I really thank you Sir. Your answer was fast and correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column in `df1`:

```
df1['C-count'] = df1['A'].map(df2.groupby('A')['C'].nunique())
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most effective way of doing this, so if your databases are too big be careful.

Define the following function:

```
def c_value(a_value, right_table):
    c_ids = []
    for index, row in right_table.iterrows():
        if row['A'] == a_value:
            if row['C'] not in c_ids:
                c_ids.append(row['C'])
    return len(c_ids)
```

For this function I'm supposing that the right_table is a `pandas.Dataframe`.

Now, you do the following to build the new column (assuming that the left table is a `pandas.Dataframe`):

```
new_column = []
for index, row in left_table.iterrows():
    new_column.append(c_value(row['A'],right_table))
left_table["C-count"] = new_column
```

After this, the left_table Dataframe should be the one dessired (as far as I understand what you need).